# Is it possible to get list of keys changed in redis server?

Tags: redis

I'm getting over 10000 updates in 60 seconds in my Redis server and this triggers the background save which consumes resources.

I want to track the changed keys so that I can debug my app (which method causing this much change).

Is there a way to get updated keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `MONITOR` is perfectly valid, it does include everything that gets sent to Redis. That means filtering read requests, pings, ...

Instead I recommend that you check the [keyspace notifications](http://redis.io/topics/notifications) documentation and configure your database the `AK` flags. By subscribing to the `__keyspace:*` pattern you'll be notified about every change to keys.

Answer (score 0):

As I learned, it's only possible by using MONITOR command and figure out from output.